# Calculate the area of a polygon from its Fourier Descriptors

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis

Is it possible to calculate the area of a polygon from its elliptical Fourier Descriptors (e.g. Zahn & Roskies, 1972)?

For example, the coefficient $G_0$ represents the centroid, and $(|G_{-1}|\cdot|G_{+1}|)^{0.5}$ the area of the fundamental ellipse.  I was hoping that there is a closed form solution to calculate the actual area of the original polygon by considering additional coefficients. The alternative would be to reconstruct the polygon from the coefficients and then use the surveyor's formula/shoelace formula to calculate the area.